# Regex to check a string against several substrings with OR at once, Hive, regex_substr

Tags: regex, string, hive

I am trying to get regex that would search string for one of the substrings I have in list and return it.
Example: list of substrings to extract {'foo', 'bar', 'one', 'two', 'ten'}. If two or more from this list are found, I only need the first found.

```
    jhgdjch_foo_hgfv -> foo 
    jhgjhs_bar_fkfj -> bar 
    kjhd_ten_67_bar -> ten
```

I am going to use it inside regexp_extract() in Hive. I wonder if I can specify OR inside regex.

Comment: regexp_extract() uses Java regex, see [Pattern javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). One tip for regexp in Hive; if your pattern includes a semicolon (;), be sure to escape with backslash, else Hive will see it and treat as end of command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do alternation.

```
/(foo|bar|ten)/
```

If you're looking for words with those in there, you'd do this:

```
/\w+_(foo|bar|ten)_\w+/
```

Do you have a tutorial you're learning regexes from?  If not, that would be an excellent move to make, because this is a very basic question.

Comment: Why not split the string on `_` and then iterate over the substrings array and filter the newly split string array for a possible match for each substring?

Comment: Thanks!! I don't have '_' characters, I only placed them to emphasize the substring I am looking for.